# What is the Software Engineering equivalent of a traditional Engineering Change Order (ECO)?

Tags: documentation, communication, development-environment

What best practices do large software companies recommend when introducing a breaking-change to their software development process? Put another way, how do you best communicate these changes to fellow developers?

For example:

- compiler bump / switch
- library upgrade
- dependency introduction

Comment: Are you sure that the purpose of an ECO is to communicate something to developers? I worked in an organization that had a manufacturing group. An Engineering Change Request (ECR) was used to initiate engineering design activities by identifying who wants the change and its intended outcome. Engineering design happens, then the ECO was used to inform the manufacturing process to use the new design. It's a communication to the manufacturing department, not engineering. It identified what components have changed, when to start making the change, and so on.

Comment: Also, how big of a development team do you have that it's non-trivial to have everyone be aware of someone working on adding or updating a tool or library? Most of these things require some level of effort and almost always expand at least a couple of calendar days for a major change and minor or patch changes should have relatively little impact.

Comment: And my final question is who runs the software? If you're a SaaS provider changing software used by a number of customers, it's going to look different than a development team building and running internal software for the business they are part of. Understanding the relationship between the development team and the people using the software affect communicating changes, both internally and externally.

Comment: Your question looks to be potentially interesting but it bears some ambiguities that need to be clarified first: 1) define what an ECO is (otherwise answers might be based on wrong assumptions); 2) is it a change affecting the software development process itself (“let’s go back to waterfall”) or is the change about the output of the development process (e.g. “let’s add this new feature”)? 3) title doesn’t match the narrative: are you genuinely interested in the ECO equivalent (i.e. one specific solution: the closest match), or do you want the best alternative in which case, define “best”?

Comment: No response to the former questions => downvoted and voted for closing ("needs details or clarity").

Comment: Given the fact that there are 3 close votes and 4 widely varying answers, I concur with Doc Brown - this question needs more details and clarity. If it addresses the questions that I and Christophe brought up, I think it could easily be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

There *are* companies that develop software and maintain servers with an explicit change order process. It may literally be called a change order. There are banks where you require a physical signature from a senior manager to change things on the "live" system.

This process has generally been phased out and replaced by more agile (and capital-A Agile) systems in which the change specification is simply captured in a ticket in a system such as JIRA.

Consultancy organisations also like calling things "change order", because that is something that can be charged for. [Here's a random example of HP talking about ECOs.](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/services/perevent/valupack/vp126.pdf) Note the prices.

Comment: Even in Agile methodologies, if you're dealing with systems in or supporting regulated entities, it's not uncommon to have some kind of gating in place - a series of approvals, electronic signatures, and so on - something more than just a ticket in a ticketing system, though.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Software Engineering equivalent of a traditional Engineering Change Order (ECO)?

Whenever I see a sentence that compares "Software Engineering" with "Engineering" or "traditional Engineering" or "other Engineering", my immediate reaction is: *which* Engineering?

Civil Engineering, Human-Factors Engineering and Aerospace Engineering don't work the same way, why should Software Engineering? You don't build a bridge the same way as you build a vaccine, so why should you build software the same way?

So, the first question you need to ask yourself is: given that Software Engineering is different from other Engineering disciplines (just like every Engineering discipline is different from every other Engineering discipline), does it even make sense to apply concepts from other Engineering disciplines to Software Engineering?

The second question is: *if* we decide that it is appropriate to draw an analogy between Software Engineering and another Engineering discipline, then which one and how do we draw the analogy?

For example, many people draw an analogy with construction. We are even using terms like "Architect" and we "build" our systems. Typically, the analogy works like this: an Architect creates a Blueprint (UML Diagram), which is then handed to a Construction Crew (Development Team) made up of expendable, exchangeable, unskilled, cheap Construction Workers (Programmers) who then build a brick wall (write some source code). That's generally where the idea that programmers are freely exchangeable cheap resources comes from.

Except this analogy has at least two problems: one, that's not actually how construction works. Many construction workers are highly skilled, uniquely qualified specialists. And two, the source code is not really the end product. The end product is the running / runnable system. Which makes the *compiler* the unskilled, cheap "worker", makes the source code the blueprint makes the programmer the highly-skilled, highly-paid "architect", and makes the "Software Architect" superfluous. This is just as valid an interpretation of an analogy as the first one is.

Then of course there is a whole subset of "software creators" who argue that creating software is not engineering *at all*, it is [Craftsmanship](https://manifesto.softwarecraftsmanship.org/).

One of the ways in which building software (whether we call that engineering or crafting or coding) is *fundamentally* different from lots of other Engineering disciplines *as well as* Craftsmanship is the fact that it is in some sense "recursive" or "fractal". When you build a bridge, the components out of which you build the bridge are not bridges: they are girders, cables, beams, rivets, nuts, bolts, screws, etc. And the tools you use to build the bridge are not bridges either, they are hammers and screwdrivers, welding equipment, etc.

Not so with software: programs are composed of (sub-)programs which are composed of (sub-sub-)programs which are composed of (sub-sub-sub-)programs, all the way down. And the tools we use to build programs are programs. The tools we use to manage how we build programs are programs. The tools we use to manage our teams are programs. And so on.

> Put another way, how do you best communicate these changes to fellow developers?
>
> For example:
>
> - compiler bump / switch
> - library upgrade
> - dependency introduction

Here's the thing: all of these are software. We know how to many changes to software, because the way we build software is not to sit down and write it all down in one go. We start, and then we go step by step, modifying the software at each step. We know how to manage these software changes.

And what you describe are also software changes. So, we know how to manage them: we put them in version control. We have a project management system which manages changes to software, all what you describe are changes to software, ergo, our project management system should be able to manage those changes as well.

Now, you might say: okay, I picked some bad examples. What about engineering documentation?

Well, as it turns out, most modern mainstream programming languages actually store (source) programs as (text) documents. In other words: all those tools I described above for managing changes to software are in reality actually tools for managing changes to *documents*.

So, the short answer is: presumably, you have some way of communicating the fact that one developer made a change to the code. (If you don't have that, your project is doomed anyway.) Since your development environment is also just programs, you can use the same way to communicate changes to the development environment.

So, for example, if you use a version control system so that multiple developers can work together on the code, you can also use a version control system so that they can ensure they use the same compiler version and you can use that same version control system also to make sure that they all have the same version of the process documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice here. The important part is that you communicate the change.

How you communicate; how you track who needs to be communicated with — these are all subjective and specific to the needs of your application, code library or enterprise. This is actually quite a complex process. It could involve something as simple as an e-mail list. It could be as complex as a clone of development ecosystems like GitHub. This is why solutions like GitHub, Azure DevOps, Jira, Rational Team Concert (along with many other products) were built. They bundle together version control, access rights, software build and deployment tools, an online publishing mechanism along with the potential for mass, automated communication.

On a more technical note, [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) at least prescribes a way to decide when something is a breaking change, and how to communicate that change using software version numbers. It does not address how to communicate that change to a specific audience, or how you track who needs to be communicated with.

Answer (score 0):

Any good software project should have an issue tracking system (for example [Edgewall trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/)).

Whenever a change needs to be made, a ticket would be raised in the tracking system.  This would set out what the problem is, and would also be used to record any investigations, and outcomes.  It's helpful if the tracking system is linked to the version management system.  These issues could be anything from a bug reported by a customer, to an engineering-led change of toolset.

However, there is no consistent name for a "ticket" or the tracking system that holds it.  This will vary depending on the development methodology and standards adopted by the project.

Comment: Similar to [my comment on pjc50's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/423442/what-is-the-software-engineering-equivalent-of-a-traditional-engineering-change#comment933086_423480), but a ticket is not equivalent to a typical ECO, especially in a regulated environment where you need to capture key information about the change along with approvals to make a change to a production system.